# What is the purpose of .grub file in a Plymouth theme

Tags: ubuntu, grub, plymouth

I'm learning to create my very own Plymouth theme. I found that besides the images and the scripts, the default `ubuntu-logo` theme has a file named `ubuntu-logo.grub`. What is this file for? Should I copy it to my own theme and rename?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around about plymouth, I think the file has something to do with grub2. The content of the file reads

```
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
```

Which is the color of grub2's boot menu (`red: 44, green:0, blue: 30, transparency: 0`) that you see if you have multiple OS's installed.

But I still don't know what `clear` means, or why it has an `if` statement.

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting for an explanation of `if` and https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Commands for other commands, like `background_color` and `clear`; essentially, if setting the background color succeeded, then it'll clear the screen.